# Android Game API: Leaderboard - Get a specific player score?

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard

I am using google [leaderboard api](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards#nested-class-summary).

How to get a specific player score by player id?

I want to display a merged leaderboard from scores around me([loadPlayerCenteredScores](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.html#public-methods) with [COLLECTION_PUBLIC](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardVariant.html#constants)) and scores of my friends([loadTopScores](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.html#public-methods) with [COLLECTION_SOCIAL](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardVariant.html#constants))

An example of such leadeboard could be something like this:

- friend score 2,000,000 rank **19**
- random player score 60,600 rank **2,618**
- random player score 60,500 rank **2,619**
- me score 50,390 rank **2,620**
- random player score 50,100 rank **2,621**
- random player score 48,900 rank **2,622**
- friend score 3,400 rank **99,600**

My problem is that I don't know the rank of my friends in the **COLLECTION_PUBLIC** leaderboard. How can I get it?

P.S
While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115615/android-game-api-leaderboard-get-specific-player-score) question got the same title, it's unrelated this question.

Answer (score 0):

The [LeaderboardScore interface](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore#constant-summary) can be used in this scenario, in your case you would want the `.getScoreHolderDisplayName()` and the `.getRank()` method

You will need to retrieve both collections, `COLLECTION_PUBLIC` and `COLLECTION_SOCIAL`. Iterate on both collections then just use some sorting.